# Spring load yaml list value

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there any easy way of loading list of specific objects from `yaml` file. So for example i have got `yaml` file with configuration like that :

```
list: 
  -
    name: a
    url: a.com
  - 
    name: b
    url: b.com
```

And i would like create `List<Endpoints>` from this properties. I know its very easy to do using spring boot and `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation but how can i do this using just spring ?

Answer (score 2):

Ignore my answer if you are looking for a Boot-free solution (in case you are building a library).

With `PropertiesConfigurationFactory`, `YamlPropertySourceLoader` and `MutablePropertySources` you can read a `Yaml` file into a Pojo:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class YamlTest {

    private static final String YAML_STRING =   "list:          \n" +
                                                "  -            \n" +
                                                "    name: a    \n" +
                                                "    url: a.com \n" +
                                                "  -            \n" +
                                                "    name: b    \n" +
                                                "    url: b.com";

    @Test
    public void shouldLoadYamlIntoObject() throws Exception {
        PropertiesConfigurationFactory<EndpointsHolder> propertiesConfigurationFactory = new PropertiesConfigurationFactory<>(EndpointsHolder.class);

        MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
        YamlPropertySourceLoader yamlPropertySourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();

        propertySources.addFirst(yamlPropertySourceLoader.load("list", new ByteArrayResource(YAML_STRING.getBytes()), null));
        propertiesConfigurationFactory.setPropertySources(propertySources);

        EndpointsHolder actual = propertiesConfigurationFactory.getObject();

        assertTrue(actual.getList().get(0).getName().equals("a"));
        assertTrue(actual.getList().get(1).getUrl().equals("b.com"));
    }

    public static class EndpointsHolder {

        List<Endpoints> list;

        public List<Endpoints> getList() {
            return list;
        }

        public void setList(List<Endpoints> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
    }

    public static class Endpoints {

        String name;
        String url;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
    }
}
```

Just replace `new ByteArrayResource(YAML_STRING.getBytes())` with you own datasource.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

yml file

```
list: 'a,a.com;b,b.com'
```

Component Class

```
    @Value("#{T(org.blah.spring.service.Endpoint).getEndpoints('${list}'.split(';'))}")
  List<Endpoint> endpoints;
```

And Endpoint

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Endpoint {

  private String name;
  private String url;

  public static List<Endpoint> getEndpoints(List<String> strings){
    List<Endpoint> endpoints = Lists.newArrayList();

    for(String s: strings){
      String split[] = s.split(",");
      endpoints.add(new Endpoint(split[0], split[1]));
    }
    return endpoints;
  }
}
```